# Alignment with relative and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

How could I center the blue box inside the red one ?
I see that the left side of the blue box is exactly in the middle of the red box, but I would like to center the whole blue box, not its left side. The dimensions of the boxes are not constant. I want to align regardless of boxes dimensions. Example to play with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NN68Z/). Thanks !

HTML:

```
<div id="rel">
    <span id="abs">Why I'm not centered ?</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rel {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

#abs {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to change the `<span>` tag to a `<div>`

```
<div id="rel">
    <div id="abs">Why I'm not centered ?</div>
</div>
```

Then this piece of CSS should work.

```
#rel {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 20px;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
text-align: center; }

#abs {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 50px; }
```

I think it's better to use more automation for the enclosed box as less changes would be needed should you change the size of the container box.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `left:50px` to `#abs` if that's all you want...

```
#abs {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    left:50px;
}
```

Comment: I mean that the dimensions of the boxes aren't known. I want to align regardless of boxes dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to define dimensions like that (200px x 300px and 300px x 400px), here's how it can be centered:

```
#rel {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

#abs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 49px 0 0 49px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the entire box? Or just the left/right centering?

Answer (score 0):

You can check at my solution here at http://jsfiddle.net/NN68Z/96/

I did the following to the css

```
    #rel {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        text-align: center;

        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #abs {
        display: block;
        bottom: 15px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
#abs {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: The left/right auto trick (like centering a div with margin) doesn't work here.